# How do you say "perhaps" or "maybe"?

Tags: word-comparison, word-choice, adverb

I have a very good guess about how to say "perhaps" or "maybe". But I suspect there are several ways of saying it, with varying degrees of certainty. I wanted to get a better idea.

My guess is this.

> [fortasse](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=fortasse&la=la#lexicon) (also fortassis , but rarely, and not in Caes.; [...])
>
> I.perhaps, peradventure, probably, possibly:

A few questions.

- Is *fortasse* the best word to say "maybe" or "perhaps"?
- Are *fortasse* and *fortassis* interchangeable?
- What's the difference between *forte*, *forsitan*, and *fortasse*?

Comment: Another related word is *forsitan* or (shortened) *forsan*

Comment: @brianpck Thanks for the addition. I added *forsitan* to my question.

Comment: I think both fortasse and forsitan are right. If you are also expressing desire, there is [_utinam_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dutinam)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*forte* (from *fors*, *fortis*, chance, luck etc.) simply means 'by chance'.

*fortasse* (sometimes fortassis) is a contraction from *forte an sit*, 'as it might chance to be', usually translated as 'perhaps', 'as it may be' etc.

Also found are *fors sit an* (often as one word) and its contraction *forsan*; and occasionally *forsit* (from *fors sit*).

Larger Latin-English dictionaries (almost invariably based on Freund's original Latin-German) all give examples of usage. The best choice for English into Latin is no more than a matter of style.

Comment: Is *forte an sit* > *fortasse* / *fortassis* following a standard pattern? It seems pretty non-intuitive to me.

Comment: @ktm5124 *forte* "by chance" means "maybe" in the following way: "Do you maybe have a second?" = "Do you by chance/perhaps have a second?" Use *fortasse* like, "Perhaps they will still come."

Comment: @ktm5124 But for *fortasse* and *forsitan*, I don't believe there is a real difference. Also, *fortasse* probably is not from *forte an sit*, but no one really knows what it should be. (Personally, I think there's an element of *esse* in there, but who knows.) Otherwise, Tom's right, it's largely a matter of style.